# Compare two arrays of PsCustomObjects

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to compare two arrays of `PsCustomObject`s?

Example A (order independent):

```
$Expected = @()
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='mrn'}

$Actual = @()
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='mrn'}
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}

Compare-ByFoo ($Expected $Actual).Count | Should Be 0
```

Example B (missing value):

```
$Expected = @()
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='mrn'}

$Actual = @()
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='';ColumnName='id'}
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}

Compare-ByFoo ($Expected $Actual).Count | Should Be 1
```

Example C (missing property):

```
$Expected = @()
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='mrn'}

$Actual = @()
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient'}
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}

Compare-ByFoo ($Expected $Actual).Count | Should Be 1
```

Example D (missing record):

```
$Expected = @()
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}
$Expected += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='mrn'}

$Actual = @()
$Actual += [PsCustomObject]@{Table='patient';ColumnName='id'}

Compare-ByFoo ($Expected $Actual).Count | Should Be 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Compare-Object` and tell it which properties to compare:

```
@(Compare-Object $Expected $Actual -Property Table, ColumnName |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }).Count
```

The properties could even be extracted from one of the expected or actual objects, provided all of them have the same structure:

```
$props = $Expected[0].PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name
@(Compare-Object $Expected $Actual -Property $props |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }).Count
```